# Multi-select Jetbrains Webstorm

Tags: multi-select, webstorm

How do I select multiple instances of text? Such as selecting all the "li" tags by highlighting one and pressing a shortcut to select the next instance and so on.
Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, you cannot. I think you're talking about the multiple cursors that are present in Sublime Text 2. But, if your text is aligned, then you can change it using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CLICK</kbd> and dragging that.

You can vote for [this feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99763) as lena mentions.

### UPDATE

This feature is now supported in Webstorm 8. If you press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and click on a different location, you will get a separate cursor there. Before, you could only drag and create cursors in the same line, however, now you can place your cursor wherever you want to.

### Keyboard Shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>

Please take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBkGOPR3-nA&feature=youtu.be) video to learn more.

Comment: Ctrl then Ctrl+Arrow Up (or Arrow Down) is the keyboard shortcut: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510243/344029

Answer (score 20):

Now you can do it in WebStorm 8 EAP (and later builds) with Select Next Occurrence (Ctrl+G on Mac and Alt+J on Windows) - See more at: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/02/webstorm-8-eap-build-134-1361-multiple-selection

Comment: `Ctrl + d` for sublime Text if you are using Sublime Text

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin for a similar effect.

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7147?pr=idea