# How can I expand multi-line selection to full lines in PHPStorm (IntelliJ IDEA)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, webstorm

In Sublime Text I can arbitrarily select a set of lines and then use `⌘+L` to expand the selection to the full lines. Is there a similar command in PHPStorm / WebStorm? (I'd like to map that command to a keyboard shortcut.)

I know PHPStorm has the option "Select Line at Caret", but that selects only one line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

Nowadays (welcome 2020) Go to Preferences > Keymap. Change or add the value to
`Add Carets to Ends of Selected Lines` => `CMD+SHIFT+L` to have it behave like Sublime Text so it looks like

[image]

**Old Answer**
This is as close as I could get it (before 2020):

Go to Preferences > Keymap. Search for `Clone Caret Above/Below`.

On a Mac, it looks like this
[image]

The keys are:

`CMD+SHIFT+CTRL+ARROW_UP` for Clone Caret Above

`CMD+SHIFT+CTRL+ARROW_DOWN` for Clone Caret Below

Click on Apply and it will work

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With WebStorm 11 (at least) the multi-caret keyboard shortcut is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> (or click & drag with the middle mouse button/scroll wheel)

then to select the full lines:

<kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

which you could even create as a [macro with a keyboard shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html).

I used to accidentally activate the multi-caret all the time (I scroll with Ctrl+Up/Down), so I knew how to do part of it, but it took me ages to figure out that extra Ctrl tap at the beginning.

Comment: This is the best answer, as there is no need to change the keymap. It works with PHPStorm 2019.1 under Linux as well.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left click on the lines you want to select. This will put multiple cursors on the editor. Now you can use the `Select Line at Caret` option you mentioned to select all those lines.

You can find more about multiple selections [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/).

Comment: Sorry, I shoudl have stated that I prefer to have a keyboard shortcut, so I don't have to use the mouse.

Comment: How do you put multiple cursors in Sublime without using the mouse? You can assign a shortcut for `Select Line at Caret`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. This is not about multiple cursors. When I'm in the middle of line and select more lines of code (SHIFT + arrow down), I would like the expand the selection of the first and last selected line from the beginning till the end of the line. This is easy with Sublime, but I cannot find something similar in PHPStorm.

Comment: BTW, on a Mac the shortcut to set multiple cursors without a mouse is CTRL + SHIFT + arrow up / down.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any way to achieve that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with a selection. However, you can still do that from the keyboard. Instead of doing selections set up a shortcut for `Clone Caret Above` (Alt+Shift+U for me) and `Clone Caret Bellow` (Alt+Shift+D for me). This allows to go up or down a line and add a caret there. So instead of selecting each line, you directly move the caret there and clone it.

I am also coming from Sublime Text and missing that feature, but this worked also pretty well.