# PHPStorm: Keyboard shortcut to initialize multiple cursors on selected lines?

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext

I used `Shift + Command (Ctrl) + L` in **Sublime Text 2.**

What is the equivalent shortcut to initialize multiple cursors on selected lines in **PHPStorm 8**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I expand multi-line selection to full lines in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165160/how-can-i-expand-multi-line-selection-to-full-lines-in-phpstorm)

Answer (score 15):

You can add it yourself.

1. Go to `Preferences` -> `Keymap`
2. Search for `Clone Caret Below` and `Clone Carrot Above`
3. Bind a shortcut (I used `Ctrl` + `Command` + `↓` for the first one)

Hit it until all the lines you want to edit have cursors :)

Comment: That's great! Thanks! It helped me a lot

Comment: `Clone Caret Below` that's what exactly we need... Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this in PHPStorm by `Alt + Click`

Comment: `Alt + click` is not equivalent here, as `Ctrl + Shift + L` is purely keyboard shortcut. You can achieve the same in Sublime with `Ctrl + click`, which was not asked in the question.

Comment: Or search for 'Add or Remove Caret' in Settings and assign your own shortcut.
In case alt + click is used for moving windows around.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand this particular functionality is not yet implemented.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on ptrogress.

Answer (score 2):

> This is now available via the [Extra Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213) plugin.

- [Credit](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181#comment=27-1310158)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/danielkurecka/intellij-extra-actions)

To enable, edit your keymap:

[image: screenshot of settings window]

Recommended shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: And do not forget remove default hotkey on MAC OS (CMD + SHIFT + L). Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> Search with Google