# Multiple cursors in PhpStorm like Sublime Text 3?

Tags: phpstorm

You can use `Alt + Click` to set multiple cursors in PhpStorm but if you want to quickly make an array of some list like this, it's simply too many lines to click: (example from Sublime Text 3)

[image]

In Sublime Text 3 you simply select all the lines and hit `Ctrl + Shift + L` and it will set cursors at the end of each line and then you can hit `Home` button to set the cursors at the beginning or whatever.

I can't find anything in docs... maybe someone knows how to do this in PHPStorm or at least how to make some keyboard shortcut with macro or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I expand multi-line selection to full lines in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165160/how-can-i-expand-multi-line-selection-to-full-lines-in-phpstorm)

Comment: No... the answer to MY question is `Alt+Shift+G` since version 2020.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such action is available from 2020.2 version -- see [IDEA-122181](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181).

It's called **Add Caret Per Selected Line** and by default has <kbd>Alt + Shift + G</kbd> shortcut on Windows (<kbd>⌥⇧G</kbd> on Mac).

---

There is also [Extra Actions plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213-extra-actions/): it claims to do that and a few other things.

---

Current alternatives (that are much easier than the mentioned <kbd>Alt + Click</kbd>):

1. Just go into **Column Selection Mode** (from the "Edit" menu, <kbd>Alt + Shift + Insert</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>Cmd + Shift + 8</kbd> on Mac). Exit that mode when done.
2. Alternatively, to add multiple carets (**Clone Caret Below** / **Above**):

   - On Windows: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice, and then without releasing it, press the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys.
   - On Mac: Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Down</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Up</kbd>
3. You can also make a multiple selection by pressing <kbd>Shift + Alt</kbd> and dragging the caret.

   From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#multiple_cursor

Comment: The PHPStorm 2020.2 is out... Do you maybe know how to do this now in new PHPStorm version?

Comment: @lewis4u Please check the ticket, the last comment in particular: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181#focus=Comments-27-4176245.0-0 : *"A VSCode-style action (which creates carets on each selected line with newly added carets not having selection) has been added. It's called 'Add Carets to Ends of Selected Lines', bound to Alt+Shift+G by default."* The shortcut might be different in different Keymap

Comment: Oh... that's it `Alt+Shift+G`

Comment: I like `Split Selection into Lines` from `Extra Actions` more than the built-in `Add Caret Per Selected Line`, as when I press `Esc` when having multiple carets, I prefer keeping the topmost caret, not the bottommost one (just like it is the case in Sublime Text). I still wish that `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below` would work like in ST, i.e. when I clone some carets upward, then I want to clone some carets downward, it should **_not_** remove the carets already created, but add some new on the next line after the bottommost caret.