# CTRL+CTRL in JetBrains IDE doesn't create carets when on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide, caret

JetBrains' documentation says that additional carets can be added like this:

> Press Ctrl twice, and then without releasing it, press up or down arrow keys.

(here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html#multiselection ; it's about Rider, but this functionality is common for all JetBrains IDEs)

This works for me in PhpStorm on Windows, but not on Ubuntu (20.04).

How can I get this to work?
Or perhaps there's an alternative key for Linux?

Comment: Try `Alt+Shift+mouse drag` or `Alt+Shift+Click`. May also use `Column Selection Mode`. P.S. In 2020.2 you can add caret to each line in selection in Sublime Text style: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62661194/783119 P.P.S. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136779#focus=streamItem-27-3232052.0-0 Also checkout shortcut for `Add or Remove Caret` action.

Comment: Thanks. These work, but they are not the same as the CTRL+CTRL technique, which doesn't :( There doesn't seem to be a mapping to it (I checked in the Windows version, where it works for me). It looks like built-in functionality.